# Firebase Cloud Messaging - How to avoid sending duplicate notifications via Firebase Web console

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Our marketing team sent out a specific notification to a set of "audience" from firebase web console. Now they want to send out another notification to new users (since last notification) but we are not able to find any attribute that can help us identify those first set of users to avoid sending them same notification again? Is it feasible to do this without any custom technical implementation by just using Firebase web console so marketing team can send out notification to newly acquired users?
Any insight/suggestions will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to target a specific subset of members of an audience.  You will have to create a new audience that collects only the people who you would like to target with messages in the future.

Comment: Hi Doug, thank you for your response. I can create the new audience but how can I exclude the old users in new audience?

Comment: You can't do that with an audience.  It will gain new members as they meet the criteria for inclusion.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!